# rails route not working but not sure why

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, actionpack

Another adopted rails app issue. I have the following in my routes.rb file. It is currently not working (not sure if it ever was). We have upgraded from 3.1 -> 3.2.13

```
scope '/arc' do 
    match '/api/get-images-by-location/:global_id' => 'api#get_images_by_location'
end
```

and I get the following error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/arc/api/get-images-by-location/168"):
```

Should this route be working? I think it should but clearly it isn't.

thx for any help

**edit 1**

Added namespace for arc

Comment: The routing error has a `/arc` in front of `/api`.  The rule provided won't catch that I believe.

Comment: The route in the error begins with `/arc/..`. Is that intended? EDIT: @NuclearGhost is correct, the rule won't catch that.

Comment: sorry, it's namespaced with a scope; edited question. There are about 100 other routes that seem to be working fine

Comment: What does `$ rake routes` say?

Comment: `rake routes` has `/api/get-images-by-location/:global_id(.:format)                                 api#get_images_by_location` I've added a , :defaults => {:format => 'json' } at the end. Let me see if that does it.

Comment: If you remove the scope part, does your route work if you hit it without the preceding `/arc`? Try and get the route working in a more simple form then add the scope back in.